# Values in nested in JSON response not being parsed

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest

I'm making a REST call to an endpoint and I'm running into an issue where the inner properties are staying strings and not converting to Javascript.

Here is what I'm getting:

```
"43750": {
    "taskId": 43750,
    "statusId": 1,
    "set_at": "2019-03-27 16:20:51",
    "userId": 2,
    "value": "[{\"text\":\"Recreational Vehicle\"}]" <-- Problem
},
```

Here is what I SHOULD be getting (old API response):

```
"43750": {
  "userId": "2",
  "timestamp": "2019-03-27 16:20:51",
  "value": [
      {
         "text": "Recreational Vehicle"
      }
   ],
   "statusId": "1"
},
```

These are snippets from the Response tab in Chrome's DevTools network section.

For some reason, arrays of objects are not being parsed into javascript and instead are remaining strings. I've set the Content Type to json in PHP and used the json datatype in the request.  What am I missing?

Frontend

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: API_URL,
        data: {
           action: 'getProject',
           projectId: this.getActiveProjectId()
        },
        success: function (response) {

            console.log('[AJAX RESPONSE] LOAD ACTIVE PROJECT', response);
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

Backend

```
<?php
$default_options = [
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        ];

$pdo = new PDO(
    sprintf(
    "dblib:host=%s;dbname=%s",
        $server,
        $database
    ),
    $user,
    $pass,
    $default_options
 );

/* Determine action, handle request */

/* Do PDO Query */    
$tasks = $statement->fetchAll();

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($tasks, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Edit:

Details about old API:

The front-end is the same. The back-end consisted of MariaDB, PHP, and the mysqli_* commands.  I'm now transitioning it to use SQL Server 2008 and PDO.

So a the last API simply did this:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Project WHERE projectId='.$projectId;
$project = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, $SQL));
while ($taskRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $project['tasks'][$taskRow['taskId']] = [
            'userId' => $taskRow['userId'],
            'timestamp' => $taskRow['timestamp'],
            'value' => json_decode($taskRow['dataValue']),
            'statusId' => $taskRow['statusId']
        ];
}

$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Task WHERE projectId='.$projectId.' ORDER BY timestamp ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($db, $SQL);
while ($commentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $project['tasks'][$commentRow['taskId']]['comments'][] = [
            'text' => $commentRow['commentText'],
            'timestamp' => $commentRow['timestamp'],
            'userId' => $commentRow['userId']
        ];
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

json_encode([
        'success' => true,
        'project' => $project
    ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Because you're `json_encode`-ing the entire object - it'll treat those things not immediately recognisable as a number as strings.

Comment: @JackBashford That doesn't seem to be an issue with the old API.  It had a Project Object with a tasks array property and was still correctly parsing them.  Is there anything to correctly coerce it I'm missing?

Comment: You seem to be storing a JSON string in your `value` column.  When you extract that from the DB, it is just a simple string, and that is how it will be treated in `json_encode()`

Comment: Also, you keep referencing an "old API".  It would probably be helpful to actually _see_ that, so we can spot the difference.

Comment: Is it maybe a feature lost by using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: The JSON datatype was added in SQL-Server 2016, so 2008 doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` column in your table contains a `JSON` string. You either need to decode it before sending the response:

```
foreach ($tasks as &$task) {
    $task['value'] = json_decode($task['value']);
}
```

or do it in the JavaScript:

```
success: function(response) {
    response.forEach(r => r.value = JSON.parse(r.value));
    // rest of success function
}
```

Comment: This step was not necessary prior (on MariaDB with PHP/mysqli_*).  Is this functionality lost by switching to SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Were you using a JSON datatype in MariaDB? SQL-Server 2008 probably doesn't have that datatype, so you're storing it as VARCHAR now. It sounds like the JSON datatype was decoded automatically, but that won't happen with VARCHAR.